# precision matlab vpa

Tags: matlab, precision

I'm working with an algorithm, which uses hyperbolic functions and in order to get more accurate results from it I need to increase the precision, so I would like to do it by vpa function means, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it. Here some code to clarify the situation further:

```
x=18; %the hyperbolic relation is valid until x=18
cosh(x)^2-sinh(x)^2
ans = 1

x=19; %the hyperbolic relation is no longer valid
cosh(x)^2-sinh(x)^2
ans = 0
```

working with the VPA function:

```
a=vpa('cosh(40)',30); %the hyperbolic relation is valid beyond x=19
b=vpa('sinh(40)',30);
a^2-b^2
ans = 1.00008392333984375
```

the problem now is that I don't know how to get the value from VPA with a variable of control 'x'

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
x=40;
a=vpa('cosh(x)',x,30);
b=vpa('sinh(x)',30);
a^2-b^2
```

Comment: x=40;a=vpa(cosh(x), 30); does not work? according to the matlab doc this should work.

Comment: @RobertStettler, I think that's the answer, the OP is just not using the right syntax. Care to make an answer out of your comment?

Comment: @A.Donda: Not quite. More importantly it's about converting from floating-point to `vpa` at the right point.

Comment: @horchler, seems you are right.

Comment: Sorry @RobertStettler

Comment: @RobertStettler it works and you will get a number, the problem here is the precision, the hyperbolic relation results in 0 because the precision isn't good enough, try the other way vpa('cosh(40)',30), you will see the difference for the first one the hyperbolica relation equals 0 but as symbolic (with quotes) equals 1

Answer (score 1):

When doing symbolic math or [variable precision arithmetic](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) one must be careful with with converting between floating-point. In this case, you need to convert your input, `x`, to variable precision *before* passing it in to `cosh` or `sinh` (otherwise only the output of these will be converted to variable precision). For your example:

```
x = vpa(40,30);
a = cosh(x);
b = sinh(x);
a^2-b^2
```

which returns the expected `1.0`. I'm not sure where you found the the use of `vpa` with string inputs, but that form is no longer used (using strings may even result in different results due to different functions being called). Note also that the default setting for [`digits`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/digits.html) in current versions of Matlab is 32.

Comment: I saw it here [link](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html?searchHighlight=vpa). Your approach also works, but what I meant with 'x' as a variable of control is to insert its value out of the vpa function, like authomatically, because I get 'x', which is a complex number, from a previous calculation